# View not display in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have install laravel in my local server. I have route with following code

```
Route::get ( '/', function () {
return view ( 'welcome' );
});
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

And controller file with following code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    echo 'test';
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    echo 'test1';exit;
    return view('welcome');
}
}
```

But i am not able to access my view file name **welcome.blade.php** in resources/views directory.
i have try following urls in web browser but i got blank page every time.

URL 1:
    http://localhost/StripeIntegration_laravel-master/public/home

URL 2: 
    http://localhost/StripeIntegration_laravel-master/public/index.php/home

URL 3:
    http://localhost/StripeIntegration_laravel-master/public/

Please help me to solve out this.

Comment: Just remove exit `echo 'test1';exit;` here in `index` method

Comment: "_but i got blank page every time_" A blank page? No `test1` on it?

Comment: It just show me **test** from constructor not even display **test1** nor display view file code if i remove exit from index file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check your code if your current code runs then Your output display will appear like this:

> testtest1

If you remove `exit;` from your index function then Your output display will appear like this:

> testtest1 //And along with the code of your welcome file will also be printed here

---

**HomeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'test1';
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: not i have already check by removing exit from index function, it is not working.

Comment: check properly @AdarshBhatt I tested the code before I posting here

Comment: I have check 3 times @UdhavSarvaiya it is not working. it only show **test** not even **test1**

Comment: I have reinstall laravel and use same code it is work properly. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `exit;` from your index function

```
public function index()
{
    echo 'test1';
    return view('welcome');
}
```

Comment: I have already check by removing exit from index(); it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have `public` in your URL.

Your webserver should be pointing at the public directory as the web root and the URL you need should be http://localhost/StripeIntegration_laravel-master/home

Answer (score 0):

first of all, remove the `echo 'test';` in the construct function, then I want to say to u that this code doesn't make sense at all: `exit; return view('welcome');`

in your controller. if you go to `localhost/yourprojectname/public`  it should show the welcome view since the root in your route says it returns the welcome view :

```
Route::get ( '/', function () {return view ( 'welcome' );});
```

if u got any questions, feel free to ask